# Configure WLAN as metered or tethered in macOS

Tags: network, wifi, tethering

MacOS seems to assume a WLAN connection to be free of charge if and only if it is not a tethered iPhone connection. So it will run all background update and maintenance processes via that WLAN connection. As my WLAN is in fact a small box with LTE access (payed by volume) I would like to configure the connection as if it were a tethered mobile connection, which it really is.

The answers to the similiar question [Managing Metered Connections on OSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215454/managing-metered-connections-on-osx) all recommend some third party tools, how can I solve it solely with built-in functionality and tools (macOS Sierra, if it helps)?

Comment: I’ve added an answer to the linked question about using network link conditioner. The canonical, “I wish to shape network traffic” question here is currently https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connections-on-the-mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you cannot without a third party extension.

In this question: [How does iOS and OS X detect when a Wi-Fi network is a personal hotspot?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199163/how-does-ios-and-os-x-detect-when-a-wi-fi-network-is-a-personal-hotspot)

There is an answer that describes how OS X detects whether the connection is a personal hotspot and it seems that there is some meta data that's embedded within the signal that identifies it as a hotspot or not.  (There's even some code that checks for if it's a carplay device, too)

> Apple controls the Hardware, the Drivers and the Operating System, I
>   guess they can easily add extra metadata when broadcasting the WiFi
>   signal so your Mac knows to whether adding the chain icon or not.

Comment: Since October 24, 2022, when macOS Ventura 13 launched, it [is available](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449668/what-is-low-data-mode-on-macos-ventura-wlan-exactly/460953#460953) under *Apple menu > System Settings > Wi-Fi* in the sidebar or *Menu Bar > Wi-Fi status icon > Wi-Fi Settings... .* Then for the active connection at the top *Details... > Low data mode*